# delete_post_meta() not deleting anything in wp_postmeta

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to delete some post meta, which is saved in table wp_postmeta, meta_value like this:

```
$v = "{"cuwzrcfofpsphjgslmbe":{"label":"10:00","hour":"10","minute":"00","period":"","add_time":"enabled","eegqepwzbupzfqzuhzay_add_date":"30\/05\/2021","eegqepwzbupzfqzuhzay_stock":"","gsmbgxjgjcakumbkjycg_add_date":"31\/05\/2021","gsmbgxjgjcakumbkjycg_zoom_id":"","gsmbgxjgjcakumbkjycg_stock":""}}"

delete_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, maybe_unserialize( $v ) );
```

$post_id and $meya_key are correct.

But nothing happens.
Any ideas?

Thanks, Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like doing

```
$v = wp_slash( $v );
```

before deleting solves it.

Comment: If this solves your problem you are encouraged to mark this answer as accepted